# How can I Call Jquery Function From Other JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, scope

**How can I call the Jquery Function From other javaScript Function (Not 
from jquery function)**
i.e 
I have written some Jquery code like below

```
 $(document).ready(function()  
 {  

   function func1(){
    // Do Something.
    }  
 });
```

Now I want to call the func1() function from other JavaScript Function

i.e Say an Example

```
function callJqueryFunction(){
 **func1();**  
}
```

The above javaScript function calling not work

but If do the same code inside a

```
$(document).ready(function()  
 {  

   function func1(){
    // Do Something.
    }  

   **func1();**    
 });
```

Its Work fine.

So what can I do for call the function which is inside a Jquery code
format.

Answer (score 3):

this has nothing to do with jquery in general, it's just a scoping issue

```
function foo() 
{
   function bar() {
        ....
   }

   bar() // Ok
}

bar() // Not OK
```

function 'bar' is "local" in foo and is not visible outside of it.
if you want a function to be used in different contexts, declare it globally.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't func1 scoped inside that ready function?  If you declare func1 outside of ready it should be available to other javascript code just as any other function.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function()  
 {  
   func1();
 });

function func1()
{
// Do something
}

function SomeOtherJavascriptFunction()
{
    func1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `func1` is defined in the scope of the parent function. If you don't need this, you can simply move the definition outside (I expect in case of `$(document).ready` you don't really need it). Otherwise you will need to pass/store the function reference somewhere, and use that to call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var funcToCall;

$(document).ready(function()  
 {  

   funcToCall = function func1(){
    // Do Something.
    }  
 });


funcToCall();
```